# VirtualBox in CentOS6 - Failure to create a new virtual machine

Tags: virtualbox, centos

The following error appears when I try to install a virtual machine in centos 6, since i removed everything and install again, but I still get the error ...

```
Failure to create a new virtual machine.

Machine settings file '/home/delkav/xp/xp.vbox' already exists.

Código Resultado: VBOX_E_FILE_ERROR (0x80BB0004)
Componente: Machine
Interfaz: IMachine {5eaa9319-62fc-4b0a-843c-0cb1940f8a91}
Receptor: IVirtualBox {c28be65f-1a8f-43b4-81f1-eb60cb516e66}
```

uname -a

```
Linux 2.6.32-279.5.2.el6.i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux - CentOS6 and Oracle VM VirtualBox Manager 4.1.22
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verify again that you are installing the right installer w.r.t to your architecture and linux distribution. In this case 32 bit.

Looks like the error comes with the reinstall. It is trying to create a machine settings file in the default path. Try again after moving the file using `mv -f /home/delkav/xp/xp.vbox /home/delkav/xp/xp.vbox.bkp`.